# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: requests

Tags: python

idle is giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.py", line 10, in <module>
    data_read = open(data)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'line1\r\nline2\r\nline3
```

i tried to parse ini, json, yml allways the same error
the code:

```py
import requests

data = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/R9cqXVYN").text

data_read = open(data)

while True:
    line = data_read.readline()
    if not line:
       break

    print(line.strip())

data_read.close
```

Comment: You don't need to `open()` text data. It's not a file-like object.

Comment: You don't open `response.text` as a text file, or if it's actually returning a text file path from the request text, the path is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in having `open(data)`. That would work if, say, `data` was a path to a local file, but `data` is already text, so your code just needs to be:

```
import requests

data_read = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/R9cqXVYN").text

for line in data_read.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: `if not line` will never be triggered and `line.strip()` isn't really useful here as `splitlines()` is invoked :) But yes, that will do the work!

Comment: In fact, `if not line` is a really bad idea, if you have an empty line then you will stop your loop before the end

Comment: @Ankirama feel free to edit my answer to your liking.